# What does 'must have an argument of class or enumerated type' actually mean

Tags: c++

I have a header file and a .cpp file. I an needing to write functions for my .h file but i get an error before i can fully complete a skeleton .cpp file.

Money.h

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
#define MONEY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Money
{
public:
   Money(int dollars, int cents);
   Money operator+(const Money& b) const;
   Money operator-(const Money& b) const;
   Money operator*(double m) const;
   Money operator/(double d) const;

   void print() const;

private:
   int dollars;
   int cents;
};

#endif
```

Money.cpp

```
#include "Money.h"

Money::Money(int dollars, int cents){

}
Money operator+(const Money& b) {

}
Money operator-(const Money& b) {

}
Money operator*(double m) {

}
Money operator/(double d) {

}

void print(){

}
```

The errors are with the multiply and divide operators:

> Money.cpp:12:25: error: 'Money operator*(double)' must have an
>   argument of class or enumerated type
>
> Money.cpp:15:25: error: 'Money operator/(double)' must have an
>   argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in the body of the question. I see a question in the title, but I'd like a little more context than just code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not using the scope resolution operator to tell the compiler that you are defining a member function. It is instead interpreted as a *global* operator overload, which takes two arguments, one of which must be of class or enumerated type. This basically means that one of your arguments must either be a user-defined type (type that is not a [primitive type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712840%28v=vs.71%29.aspx%E2%80%8E)) or an [enumerated type](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html%E2%80%8E) which is defined through an `enum`.

In your original code `Money` is just the return type; it doesn't tell the compiler that you are defining member function from that class.

Here is a fix for one of your lines:

```
Money Money::operator+(const Money& b)                                         /*
      ^^^^^^^                                                                  */
{
     // ...
}
```

Moreover, your prototypes and definitions must also match in cv-qualification. Your definitions were missing the `const` qualifier...

```
Money Money::operator+(const Money& b) const                                   /*
                                       ^^^^^                                   */
{
     // ...
}
```

---

Update:

I also found that your definition for `Money::operator*` and `Money::operator/` do not match their prototypes. The prototypes for both take a `double` while the definitions take `Money const&`. You will need to change one to match the other.

```
// inside Money class

Money operator*(Money const&) const;
Money operator/(Money const&) const;
```

Comment: I did think that was the problem but it gave me this error: 'prototype for 'Money Money::operator*(double)' does not match any in class 'Money''

Comment: don't forget `const` in the function signation

Comment: @user1082764 Your prototypes and definitions must also match in cv-qualification.

Comment: @user1082764 Because you need to add `const` to the end: `Money Money::operator*(double) const { ... }`. Do this to all the definitions so that they match.

Comment: @Downvoter I don't understand the downvote but if you would care to explain it would be appreciated.

Comment: @billz Hmm...I always thought that to be true. So why is it not correct?

Comment: @user1082764 Please see my edit, the signature of your prototype and your definitions do not match. One takes a double while the other takes a `const Money&`.