# Possible to overload operator* to multiple an int and a char*?

Tags: c++, overloading

I would like to get functionality so I can do this:

```
std::cout << "here's a message" << 5*"\n";
```

I tried the following:

```
std::string operator* (int lhs, const char* rhs) {
  std::string r = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < lhs; i++) {
    r += rhs;
  }
  return r;
}
```

And I got this error message:

```
error: ‘std::string operator*(int, const char*)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

According to the answers in this SO post [What does 'must have an argument of class or enumerated type' actually mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139490/what-does-must-have-an-argument-of-class-or-enumerated-type-actually-mean) it almost seems like I can't do this period. Is that really the case? If not, how do I fix this or arrange a workaround?

What I know I can do is have `rhs` as a `std::string`, but then the whole point of the exercise is half foregone, as `5*std::string("\n")` is quite clunky.

Comment: You can't overload operators for built in types.

Comment: Try using `typedef const char* MyString` and then try to implement your function for `MyString` parameter type. I'm not sure it will work but I would try it

Comment: In C++14, `5 * "\n"s` is less clunky. However, my first impression is that `repeat("\n", 5)` is more readable than both.

Comment: @SomethingSomething No, that won't work.

Comment: `std::string concat(std::size_t n, const std::string&)`

Comment: @SomethingSomething I liked your idea of trying to cheat the compiler, but it saw through the trick sadly.

Comment: @DieterLücking Hi Dieter thank you for your suggestion. I feel very silly, but I can't find this function in the STL, are you suggesting I implement this function or is it part of the STL?

Comment: @Hurkyl I just tried your recommended expression with C++14 and it says unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""s’   ...also for your repeat suggestion, are you just suggesting I implement a function called repeat or is there such a function in the STL I am not aware of?

Comment: Ah yes I meant implement a function called `repeat`. Regarding the string literal operator, it looks like you need to do `using namespace std::string_literals;` first.

Comment: @Hurkyl got it. Thanks very much for the followup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achive it with user-defined literals. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string operator"" _s(const char* s) { return std::string(s); }

std::string operator"" _s(const char* s, std::size_t len) { return std::string(s, len); }

std::string operator* (unsigned int k, std::string s) {
    std::string t;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) 
        t += s;

    return t;
}

std::string operator* (std::string s, unsigned int k) { return k * s; }

int main() {
    std::cout << "Jump!"_s * 5 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: sorry I had a typo. Now it works great. Thanks a lot for this clever solution. Can I ask one question? Why does the string go on the left in the expression but somehow end up on the right in the operator overload?

Comment: @sunny, I have two versions of overload specifically so that associativeness of operator * can be preserved.

Comment: Ugh sorry I missed that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

From [over.oper]:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function that has
>   **at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration**.

So you can't overload an operator whose parameters are both builtins. Furthermore, in order for `operator*(int, std::string)` to be found, it'd have to be in `namespace std` and it's ill-formed to add definitions to that namespace.

Instead, you could simply provide a small wrapper:

```
struct Mult { int value; };
```

and provide overloads for it:

```
std::string operator*(const Mult&, const char* );
std::string operator*(const char*, const Mult& );
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. this is at least a bit less clunky than using 5*std::string("\n") so I will probably try this. Thanks!

Comment: @sunny, look at my suggestion - it is even less clunky! :)

Comment: @Barry I am trying to implement your suggestion (I'm implementing them all to compare performance as a learning exercise), but I can't seem to get this right. I keep getting a seg fault upon calling operator* which I've defined as: std::string operator*(const Mult& m, const char* c){ 
  std::string t = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < m.value; ++i) {
    t += c;
    }
};

Comment: Even when the function is empty it throws a seg fault. Any insights?

Comment: @sunny Missing `return`?

Comment: eek you are right! sorry about that and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Barry looks like this solution is the fastest. Seems to be about 10% faster than the other solutions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

From C++ FAQ [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading),

> C++ language requires that your operator overloads take at least one
>   operand of a “class type” or enumeration type. The C++ language will
>   not let you define an operator all of whose operands / parameters are
>   of primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

You neither can nor must overload that op;

[string ctor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) does the job for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "here's a message:\n" 
              << std::string(5, '\n') 
              << "EOF" << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
here's a message:






EOF
```

[(live at Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c401b8264984b3)