# Implicit conversion with operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is in part inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572768/possible-to-overload-operator-to-multiple-an-int-and-a-char) question. When I write the code:

```
void test(std::string inp)
{
  std::cout << inp << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  test("test");
  return 0;
}
```

`"test"` is implicitly converted from `const char*` to `std::string`, and I get the expected output. However, when I try this:

```
std::string operator*(int lhs, std::string rhs)
{
  std::string result = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < lhs; i++)
  {
    result += rhs;
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::string test = 5 * "a";
  return 0;
}
```

I get the compiler error, `invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator*'`. `"a"` was not implicitly converted to `std::string` here, instead it remained a `const char*`. Why is the compiler able to determine the need for an implicit conversion in the case of a function call, but not for the case of an operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, operators have different rules from other kinds of functions.

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator
>   is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

([over.match.oper]/1)

Comment: Normally I'd say, "Add in Clause 5 for completeness." but fifty-something pages seems excessive.

Comment: Indeed, implicit conversion works as anticipated for non-primitive types; see [here](http://ideone.com/K4K2vS).